# Make bigger field for touch and drag node, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making  small paddle node whom can touch and drag in defined area. The problem is that paddle is small wich makes for finger unresponsive. My question is how can i make area around node bigger without making node bigger. Here are What Iam working on:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];
      if (self) {

    self = [PaddleNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"board.png"];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.name = name;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = paddleCategory;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = emptyCategory;
    self.currentTouchValue = nil;
}

   return self;
}

   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
        self.previousTouchesTimestamp = event.timestamp;


for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    self.currentTouchValue = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:touch];
}
 }

   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

self.currentTouchValue = nil;
  }

  - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:touch];
    if ([key isEqualToValue:self.currentTouchValue]) {

        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
        CGPoint movePoint = CGPointMake(self.position.x, touchPoint.y);
        if ([self withinParentFrame:movePoint])
            self.position = movePoint;
    }
}

  }

 - (BOOL)withinParentFrame:(CGPoint)point
 {
CGFloat offset = self.size.height / 2;
if (point.y >= offset && point.y <= self.scene.frame.size.height - offset)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
 }
```

**Edited :** I read

> UITouch Class Reference

documentation. As I understand that, I can't do it in *touchesMoved*, but I find my old project, were are same code, but there I can put my finger anywhere on screen, and node will move in nodes defined area.
**Edited 2** This question is still unanswered and important to me!